# One-time AlertDialog showing on every run

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to have a disclaimer pop up when the app is first run, and after each update.  I did a bunch of googling and reviewed some questions here as well, and this is what my code looks like:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
String lver = pref.getString("Version", "");
String ver = this.getString(R.string.version);
if(ver != lver)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Disclaimer")
        .setMessage(this.getString(R.string.disclaimer))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                accepted = true;
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Decline", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MainMenu.this.finish();
            }
        });
    AlertDialog disc = builder.create();
    disc.show();
    if(accepted == true)
    {
        edit.putString("Version", this.getString(R.string.version));
        edit.commit();
    }
}
```

This code actually worked at first, but when I changed my apps starting activity, and moved this code from the original starting activity to the new one, it no longer works.  The disclaimer appears on every run.

I want the popup only to show on first run and after updates.  What do I need to do to achieve this?  I am very frustrated and confused by the fact that it was working, then wasnt.

Comment: Don't ever compare `Strings` in Java using `==` or `!=`. You have an `if` condition `if(ver != lver)`. Change that to use the `equals(...)` method of `String` as follows... `if(!ver.equals(lver))`.

Comment: I made that change.  Just to verify I'm understanding the syntax you gave, the ! before the first variable name makes it if not equal to?

Comment: And also, making that change didnt solve the issue, still comes up every run.

Comment: Yes `!` means `NOT` therefore `!someString.equals(someOtherString)` means "not equal to". If changing it to use `if(!ver.equals(lver))` hasn't fixed it then either there's a problem with `R.string.version` or with the `Version` preference. Are you saving that using the name `version`? Preferences are case-sensitive - if you are saving as `version` and trying to retrieve as `Version`, then the default `""` of `pref.getString("Version", "")` will be applied.

Comment: No, both saving and retrieving as `Version`.  You can see the storage at the bottom of the snippet, and the retrieval at the top.

Comment: OK, sorry, missed the saving part.

Comment: Ah, OK. You need to put the saving of the version into the `onClick(...)` method of the `OnClickListener` of the `.setPositiveButton` call of the dialog builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing Strings with .equals() is the correct way (see: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for a good explanation) , although because I'm not sure how the android internals work and you said it worked before, that isn't your problem. Your problem is that your check

```
if (accepted == true) {/** code */}
```

isn't run on the on click listener. Because it isn't, that thread (I'm assuming it spawns a new thread to show the dialog) keeps running.

I'm also assuming before you moved this code, you had declared a

```
boolean accepted = true; //or initialized it to true somewhere
```

But when you moved it you didn't reinitialize it. Now, because the default value of a primitive is false, in your new code it gets to the check before you press a dialog button, and never commit the new version.

My advice would be put what's in the

```
accepted == true
```

block simply into your listener for the positive button click.

Comment: "My advice would be put what's in the 
`accepted == true`
block simply into your listener for the positive button click."
If I do this i get the error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable edit inside an inner class defined in a different method".

Comment: EDIT: Ok - you can either make pref a final variable (and only create the editor on the positive button being pressed as you don't use it elsewhere) or in the accept call a function you defined. So I'd just

    final SharedPreferences pref ...

    ...
 public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
     SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
  //Handle your edit code. 
 }

Comment: However, your second thing was correct.  I had moved the boolean declare, but for some reason did it as false instead of true, therefore the version was never being stored lol.